# Maven local repository for jenkins builds

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, pom.xml

I have a unix server hosting my jenkins instance. More than 100 projects are configured for auto deployment in Jenkins. I would like to avoid all the projects specifying the repositories in the respective pom files(3rd party, central). Instead I can have a central configuration pointing to all the central and 3rd party repos. Anyone has done this before?

Comment: Provided all of the deployments use the same maven installation, you can specify repositories in `settings.xml`.

Comment: What modifications would I need to make in all the individual project poms?

Comment: I think none are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a *site-wide* `.setting.xml` file for all of your developers to use. This would sit in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` directory. However, there's no way to force developers to do this. They can still put this information into their `pom.xml` and unless you're using some sort of commit hook, you may not be able to detect it.

However, if you use either [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) in your environment, it will make it easier for developers to configure their `pom.xml` without having to include repository information.

Artifactory can even strip out repository configuration in `pom.xml` files that are downloaded to the server. This is even true with third party `pom.xml` files too. Both will help generate a site-wide `setting.xml` file that developers can use on their systems. These systems remove the need to configure repository information in your `pom.xml` file -- even if this is a non-standard repository location. You simply add this configuration into Artifactory or Nexus. No need to modify the various `settings.xml` files or the `pom.xml`.

You can't prevent a stubborn developer who ***insists*** that the right way to write a `pom.xml` is with configured repository information, but you can make the developer's job easy enough that they no longer have to worry about repository configurations, and most developers will be more than happy not to do that if they don't need to.